# Cyclomatic complexity of scala

Tags: java, scala

Is there a tool for generating cyclomatic complexity of scala code ?

Thank You

Comment: If there was one, I doubt the number would tell you much about the real complexity of the code. You can write very complex code by putting folds and maps and filters together but the cyclomatic complexity will stay low.

Comment: Is cyclomatic complexity meaningful for functional code?

Comment: @Stephen, i dont know much about scala now, but why wouldnt it?

Comment: @Suraj - because for (true) functional points there are no obvious branch points.  Also what @Kim said.

Comment: @Stephen - A functional point could (but not definitely) count as a branch point. Perhaps a different type of complexity metric would be required for true FP languages. In the case of Scala (and similar languages), cyclomatic complexity might still need to be used but with some grain of salt, but current cyclo-complex tools won't work with it.

Comment: @Stephen - cont' - the way I see it, running a cyclo-complex metric on a Scala program can shed light on which methods are using traditional branching constructs. Then people can reason about whether to rewrite/refactor those pieces into FP style equivalents (where it makes sense to do so.) That is, one could use a cyclo-complex metric tool as a mean to guide refactoring and detect red flags. That's how people do with trad. langs anyways. So the same could be done with langs **with FP support** (but not for true FP langs) while look at the results from a different angle.

Answer (score 30):

To the best of my knowledge, there are no such tools.  I think it's important to note that cyclomatic complexity is a fundamentally *procedural* metric, and it falls over completely when you have higher-order functions in your language.  If you write code in "good" Scala style, the cyclomatic complexity *literally* goes to 1 for your entire code base.  The reason is that higher-order frameworks have a tendency to avoid explicit branches altogether.  Everything is encoded in terms of functions, and it's not particularly clear how to measure the cyclomatic complexity of a higher-order function (hence, everything goes to 1).

I would advise you to abandon the idea of measuring cyclomatic complexity in the context of Scala, or really any other functional language.  A better, and actually more informative metric, would be to simply grep through the code for `if` and `match`/`case` statements.  When you find them, *consider* making them go away.  These statements aren't bad by any means, but there are many cases where they can be replaced by a straight-line, higher-order function.  This examination will accomplish the same goal as a cyclomatic complexity metric, but much more usefully w.r.t. the functional paradigm.  And, at the end of the day, it is likely that your code will be far more "functional" and vastly more composable as a result.

To extend Daniel's comment, the same issues actually arise any time you can encode higher order functions. That means, in particular, cyclomatic complexity doesn't apply well to OO. If a method calls b.foo then there is an invisible branch point - a branch to any of the foo methods that could possibly be reached that way. Yet most cyclomatic complexity measures for Java or whatever don't count messsage sends as branch points. It's entirely possibly (though not commonly practiced) to remove all ifs, all fors and whiles, etc via plain old OO. The only difference between OO and FP along these lines is that replacing loops and conditionals with higher level constructs is considered normal FP practice.

Comment: @Daniel: +1 You're suggesting to remove if and match/case statements. I guess this is also true for while and for statements as they are not really functional. Your are right, you will eventually end up with a cyclomatic complexity of 1 for each method bacause the ccn calculation in pratice is typically done by counting exactly those statements. So, why not make this an explicit goal? Try to reach a ccn of 1 for each method in scala!

Comment: @Steffen - I don't buy it.  A pattern match and a fold are the same thing expressed differently.  In some cases one will be a better fit than the other.  Screw arbitrary metrics that don't tell you anything.

Comment: @James: I don't want to encourage people to use ccn with functional languages. All I tried to express is, that if the advise is to replace those language constructs with more functional approaches one eventually follows the same goal as trying to reach a ccn of 1.  At least if you are calculating the ccn the same way as for procedural languages.

Comment: @Steffen - I'm writing a language and even though I'm just getting started my AST has 10 different node types already.  I could do everything with a fold that takes 10 different functions.  But I don't, I use pattern matching.  I don't care if some tool says that increases my complexity. Pattern matching brings advantages in expressiveness - I can say very complex things in a small space.

Comment: @Steffen - at the same time, I tend to collect typing results in something equivalent to ScalaZ's validations (I didn't know they had such a thing at the time).  I string them together using higher order functions and almost never pattern match.  Why?  Because it happens to be a better fit.

Comment: It's funny that cyclomatic complexity is considered meaningless in Scala, since the inventor of Scala is giving a course in which keeping cyclomatic complexity down is a grading criteria.

Comment: @Daniel Could you please give (or point to) a simple example for such a refactoring? I.e. replacing match with higher order function(s).

Answer (score 15):

Scalastyle:

http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-0.5.0.html

Odersky considers cyclomatic complexity important in FP, and this *is* a Scala question.

Comment: The [Scalastyle code to measure cyclomatic complexity](https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalastyle/scalariform/CyclomaticComplexityChecker.scala) appears to count five keywords and two operators: `IF`, `CASE`, `WHILE`, `DO`, `FOR`, `&&`, `||`. This measurement takes no account of functional programming techniques. The `DefaultMaximum` should be 1 rather than 10, in purely functional Scala code, as @DanielSpiewak explains in his answer.

Comment: I imagine that Odersky offers some leeway when teaching a course because his goal is not to teach purely functional Scala… Scala is, after all, a hybrid language. Using Scalastyle to measure the cyclomatic complexity of _imperative_ Scala code highlights those Scala features which are not _functional_.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a task in the SBT tool to check for common style problems. Among other things, it will raise a warning if cyclomatic complexity goes over 10 in any block. For more details, check here: 
http://www.scala-sbt.org/

The task is called styleCheck.

Comment: Please note that the styleCheck task is specific to the Coursera course and is based upon scalastyle. If you want the same functionality in your normal build, use scalastyle.